# filtering a complex text file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a text file like this:

```
@M00872:408:000000000-D31AB:1:1102:15653:1337 1:N:0:ATCACG
CGCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACCCGCTGAATTTAAGCA
+
BCCBGGGGGGGGGGHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHH
@M00872:408:000000000-D31AB:1:1102:15388:1343 1:N:0:ATCACG
CGCGACCTCATGAATTTAAGGGCGACCCGCTGAATTTAAGCA
+
CBBBGGGGGGGGGGHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHGHHH
```

every 4 lines are belong one group and the first line of each group starts with `@`.
the 2nd line of each group is important for me so I would like to filter out the groups based on 2nd line. in fact if this specific sequence "`GATCAGACGTGGCGAC`" is present in the 2nd line, I want to remove the whole group and make a new file containing other groups.
so the result for this example is:

```
@M00872:408:000000000-D31AB:1:1102:15388:1343 1:N:0:ATCACG
CGCGACCTCATGAATTTAAGGGCGACCCGCTGAATTTAAGCA
+
CBBBGGGGGGGGGGHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHGHHH
```

I tried the following command but it returns only the 2nd line and only the ones which contain this piece of sequence. but I want the whole group and if the 2nd line does not contain this sequnce.

```
grep -i GATCAGACGTGGCGAC myfile.txt > output.txt
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The answer below is good, but just in case you didn't know, the file you have is a fastq file. There are existing tools for working with them. But again, the answer below is good.

Answer (score 2):

Single `awk` solution:

```
awk -v kw='GATCAGACGTGGCGAC' '/^@/{if (txt !~ kw) printf "%s", txt; n=4; txt=""} n-->0{
txt=txt $0 RS} END{if (txt !~ kw) printf "%s", txt}' file

@M00872:408:000000000-D31AB:1:1102:15388:1343 1:N:0:ATCACG
CGCGACCTCATGAATTTAAGGGCGACCCGCTGAATTTAAGCA
+
CBBBGGGGGGGGGGHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHGHHH
```

Alternative `grep + gnu awk` solution:

```
grep -A 3 '^@' file | awk -v RS='--\n' -v ORS= '!/GATCAGACGTGGCGAC/'

@M00872:408:000000000-D31AB:1:1102:15388:1343 1:N:0:ATCACG
CGCGACCTCATGAATTTAAGGGCGACCCGCTGAATTTAAGCA
+
CBBBGGGGGGGGGGHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHGHHH
```

Comment: @ARM: Did this help?